# Clients with broken reverse DNS are slow to connect, how to fix?

Tags: dns, reverse-dns, rdns

Some client has no reverse DNS and that clients has long timeout on connect with different services like ftp, ssh and more. How to configure reverse dns resolution right on production servers? Maybe there is way to completely disable it for all services?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to ask those clients having problems to ask their own ISPs for rDNS on their client network(s).